# How set telegraf configuration to collect kafka topic/partition lags in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, telegraf

I want to put kafka topic/partition lags in Elasticsearch.
By using kafka burrow and telegraf.

I already installed kafka, burrow, telegraf and Elasticsearch in local macbook. I knew there was a burrow-input plugin in telegraf.

telegraf burrow plugin : https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/burrow

Please tell me how to set telegraf configuration for collecting topic/partition lags in Elasticsearch.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make telegraf as data pipeline to connect Burrow and Elasticsearch. Use below configuration.

**telegraf.conf**

```
[[inputs.burrow]]
  servers = ["http://burrowIp:8000"]
  topics_exclude = [ "__consumer_offsets" ]
  groups_exclude = ["console-*"]

[[outputs.elasticsearch]]
  urls = [ "http://elasticsearchIp:9200" ] 
  timeout = "5s"
  enable_sniffer = false
  health_check_interval = "10s"
  index_name = "burrow-%Y.%m.%d" 
  manage_template = false
```

This setting will accumulate data on the Elastic Search.

[image]